# Pasting into vim over ssh repeats or drops 6 characters at random

Tags: cut-copy-paste, ssh

When I SSH into a remote Ubuntu container on a particular system and open vim, I cannot paste consistently. Say I copy the string `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` to my clipboard. If I open vim, enter insert mode, and try pasting and hitting enter a few times, the result might look like:

```
abcdefabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Note that only one line is correct; most lines repeat the first six characters of the sequence (`abcdef`), and in one instance, the first six characters are dropped. It is always six, regardless of what is on the clipboard.

A few things I have tried:

- The behavior is the same if I `:set paste` or `:set paste!`.
- I have reproduced the behavior using zsh and bash as my local shell. The remote shell is bash.
- When I paste directly into the remote shell, paste works fine. No characters are repeated or dropped. The issue only occurs in vim.
- When I run `cat -v` in the remote shell and paste, as suggested by [this answer](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard/issues/31#issuecomment-55966569), I do not see control characters related to bracketed paste mode.

Comment: Note that `:set paste!` will toggle the `paste` option. The result depends on the previous value. As far as I can tell, you use it correctly. Just something to keep in mind. Might be safer to `.set nopaste` or verify through `:set paste?`.